# How to use addEventListener to trigger on a page's ready state [no jQuery]

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The [top Google hit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5436521/1695680) for [javascript addeventlistener load](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+addeventlistener+load) was jQuery based and therefore not relevant to me, I want a clean reference of how to best bind an event to a document's ready state in vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: If you want to see exactly how to use the `readyState` to know when the DOM is ready in plain javascript across many different generations of browsers, see this answer which has a ready to use function that uses the `readyState` and the `DOMContentLoaded` event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the/9899701#9899701

Comment: Thank you jsfriend00, and indeed everyone else who has posted on this thread. I'm excited to know there are so many colorful variants!

Answer (score 2):

> how to best bind an event to a document's ready state

That would probably be...

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { });
```

Answer (score 0):

MDN's [Reference for Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events) show the [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/load) event being the desired trigger. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16406528/1695680) explains not to bind to the `document` node, rather to bind to the `window` node.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){ console.log('document ready!'); });
```

Comment: That's a different event to *document ready*. I'd call that *all stuff has downloaded*.