# What is the difference between all the following event?

Tags: javascript, arrays, event-handling

I have a question concerning the difference between:

```
 1. <body onload="myFunction()">
 2. window.onload = myFunction;
 3. window.addEventListner("load", myFunction)
 4. window.onload = myFunction();
```

So are they all equivalent? and which one is the best practice to use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [window.onload vs <body onload=""/>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191157/window-onload-vs-body-onload) and [attachEvent / addEventListener to Window onload / load - preferred way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436521/attachevent-addeventlistener-to-window-onload-load-preferred-way).  See also [How to make JavaScript execute after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/how-to-make-javascript-execute-after-page-load)

Comment: window.addEventListener is the preferred way to add events.

Comment: The best one to use is `<script type="module">` which defers by default, has implicit strict mode, and has a few other features that boost code quality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are all equivalent.  It is the same "load" event.  I prefer to use DOMContentLoaded.  That's what I check for before manipulating the DOM.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event